# Can not activate "Add a vpn connection" button in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, vpn, pptp

My OS is 16.04.2 LTS. Though i need only **pptp**, i have installed **open-vpn**, **pptp**, **openvpn-gnome**, **vpnc**, **pptp-gnome** etc for test purpose. But button haven't been activated. I had restarted my machine after every installation to check, but result was same.

How can i activate the button ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to click on Edit Connections > Add > Choose your VPN protocol. Than you should be able to configure a connection.